# Handling require_recipient action processing errors

Tags: action

What would happen if the recipient has code to handle the action notification and there is an error processing it? For instance an assertion failure? Would the whole transaction fail ?

Also, am I right to assume that the notification runs after the original action completed, regardless on where the require_recipient call appears ?

Answer (score 1):

> What would happen if the recipient has code to handle the action
>   notification and there is an error processing it? For instance an
>   assertion failure? Would the whole transaction fail ?

Yes, because it's an inline action, the entire transaction will fail. You could design a custom deferred transaction that notifies an account though, and that would run in a different transaction.

> Also, am I right to assume that the notification runs after the
>   original action completed, regardless on where the require_recipient
>   call appears ?

Yes, actions are processed sequentially at the moment. You can test this by printing something before and after a call to an inline action that triggers another print and checking the printed output order.